# Javascript filter array into new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have this data:

```
const data = [
  {  
    product_name: 'BMW',
    year: '1982'
  },
  {
    product_name: 'BMW',
    year: '1998'
  },
  {
    product_name: 'LandRover',
    year: '1982'
  },
  {
    product_name: 'BMW',
    year: '1982'
  },
  {
    product_name: 'LandRover',
    year: '1985'
  },
  {
    product_name: 'LandRover',
    year: '1981'
  }
]
```

Using vanilla javascript I need to filter the data into an array like this:

```
[
  {
    name: 'BMW',
    data: [1982, 1998, 1982]
  },
  {
    name: 'LandRover',
    data: [1982, 1985, 1981]
  }
]
```

Can anyone help? Not sure the best way to approach this.

Many thanks

Comment: you may have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-array-of-objects-by-key

Comment: I have had a go using map, but not having much luck. Would it be possible if you could show me the best way of doing it

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?  It will be easier to help if we know where you are stuck.

Comment: You need to reduce it to an object with names as the keys as the values, then map over the keys to produce the nested array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reduce`

```
var output = Object.values(data.reduce( function( a,b ){
  a[ b.product_name ] = a[ b.product_name ] || { name : b.product_name, data: [] }; //initialize the object as { name : .., data: [] }; 
  a[ b.product_name ].data.push( Number( b.year ) ); //push the year to data array after converting the same to a Number
  return a; //return the accumulator
}, {})); //finally return the object.values
```

**Demo**

```js
var data = [
  {  
    product_name: 'BMW',
    year: '1982'
  },
  {
    product_name: 'BMW',
    year: '1998'
  },
  {
    product_name: 'LandRover',
    year: '1982'
  },
  {
    product_name: 'BMW',
    year: '1982'
  },
  {
    product_name: 'LandRover',
    year: '1985'
  },
  {
    product_name: 'LandRover',
    year: '1981'
  }
];

var output = Object.values(data.reduce(function(a, b) {
  a[b.product_name] = a[b.product_name] || {
    name: b.product_name,
    data: []
  }; //initialize the object as { name : .., data: [] }; 
  a[b.product_name].data.push(Number(b.year)); //push the year to data array after converting the same to a Number
  return a; //return the accumulator
}, {}));

console.log( output );
```

Comment: Thank you. You are a star :)

Answer (score 4):

You can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the data to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), get the [Map values iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values), and then [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) it to an array:

```js
const data = [{"product_name":"BMW","year":"1982"},{"product_name":"BMW","year":"1998"},{"product_name":"LandRover","year":"1982"},{"product_name":"BMW","year":"1982"},{"product_name":"LandRover","year":"1985"},{"product_name":"LandRover","year":"1981"}];

const result = [...data.reduce((m, o) => {
  // if map doesn't have the product_name, init the object and add to map
  m.has(o.product_name) || m.set(o.product_name, {
    name: o.product_name,
    data: []
  });

  // get the product object, and add the year
  m.get(o.product_name).data.push(o.year);

  return m;
}, new Map()).values()]; // get the map values, and spread to an array

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method with a hashmap to refer index.

```
// object for refering index
const ref = {};

// iterate over the object array
let res = data.reduce((arr, o) => {
  // check already present in array
  if (!(o.product_name in ref)) {
    // if not present define the index reference
    // and define object
    arr[ref[o.product_name] = arr.length] = {
      name: o.product_name,
      data: []
    };
  }
  // push into the data array
  arr[ref[o.product_name]].data.push(o.year);
  // return array reference
  return arr;
  // set initial value as array
}, [])
```

```js
const data = [{    product_name: 'BMW',    year: '1982'  },  {    product_name: 'BMW',    year: '1998'  },  {    product_name: 'LandRover',    year: '1982' },  {    product_name: 'BMW',    year: '1982'  },  {    product_name: 'LandRover',    year: '1985'  },  {    product_name: 'LandRover',    year: '1981'  }];

const ref = {};

let res = data.reduce((arr, o) => {
  if(!(o.product_name in ref))  arr[ref[o.product_name] = arr.length] = {      name: o.product_name,      data: []    };  
  arr[ref[o.product_name]].data.push(o.year);
  return arr;
}, [])

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function

```
    function convert(datas) {

        var hash_result = {}

        datas.forEach(function(data) {
          console.log(hash_result[data['product_name']])
          if(hash_result[data['product_name']]) {
            hash_result[data['product_name']].push(data['year'])
          } else {
            hash_result[data['product_name']] = [data['year']]
          }
        })

        var result = []

        Object.keys(hash_result).forEach(function(key) {
          result.push({
            name: key,
            data: hash_result[key]
          })
        })

    return result
  }
```